# Punctuation in Java source changed to accented letters when copied to IFS

Tags: character-encoding, ftp, ibm-midrange, rpgle, ibm-ifs

I am trying to run a RPGLE program which use java methods. I am transfering the java code (xxxx.java file) from my system(Windows XP) to the AS/400 IFS directory through FTP. After transfering it to IFS, the file CCSID is shown as 819.

I am compiling the .java file in QSH, no error is shown. But two class files are generated. i.e.
`Mailer.java` → `Mailer.class` and `Mailer$1.class`

But when I am calling my RPGLE program, a java exception is shown...

```
Java exception received when calling Java method (C G D F)... 
Application error.  RNX0301 unmonitored by MAILERDEMO at statement 000000500
```

When I saw the `Mailer.java` file in IFS by pressing option 5, symbols like `{` , `}`, `[` , `]`, `!`, `/`, `\` etc. are changed to some other symbols.

### So plz suggest me some solutions for this, so that I can run this program. How to transfer the .java file to IFS without changing the characters to some different ones?

Here are some details.....

System CCSID Value - 819

Job CCSID - 273

My Java source code in IFS directory:

```
// Load Properties File                                                        
if (is |= null) ä                                                              
    try ä                                                                      
        properties = new Properties();                                         
        properties.load(is);                                                   
    ü                                                                          
    catch (Exception e) ä                                                      
        System.err.println("Error " + "Ö"" + e.getLocalizedMessage()           
            + "Ö"" + " loading AS/400 Connection Properties.");                
        throw new RuntimeException(e);                                         
    ü                                                                          
ü                                                                              

// Assume properties passed as system properties                               
else ä                                                                         
    properties = System.getProperties();                                       
ü
```

Java Exception shown running RPGLE program:

```
Message ID . . . . . . :   RNQ0301       Severity . . . . . . . :   99         
Message type . . . . . :   Inquiry                                             
Date sent  . . . . . . :   12/30/10      Time sent  . . . . . . :   11:31:57   

Message . . . . :   Java exception received when calling Java method (C G D    
  F).                                                                          
Cause . . . . . :   RPG procedure MAILERDEMO in program SAHOON1/MAILERDEMO     
  received Java exception "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sendSimpleMail" when   
  calling method "sendSimpleMail" with signature                               
  "(Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.lang.String;)L 
  java.lang.String;" in class "demo.Mailer".                                   
Recovery  . . . :   Contact the person responsible for program maintenance to  
  determine the cause of the problem.                                          
Possible choices for replying to message . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :       
  D -- Obtain RPG formatted dump.                                              
                                                                       More...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can compile your source with javac in QSH then the Java source code itself was transferred in a way that made it acceptable to javac (which doesn't do code page conversion and expects the bytes read to be in 819).  The Mailer$1.class comes from an anonymous class in Mailer (a new FooBar() with a {}-block afterwards).

That it looks incorrect to you, I would then expect to be because the AS/400 system is most likely not agreeing with your 5250 emulator on the character sets used, and I wouldn't worry (as long as javac works).

Your error message indicates however, that there is a mismatch between the RPG header describing what Java method you want to call, and the one which is actually there.  To me it looks like you want to invoke "demo.Mailer.sendSimpleMail(String, String, String, String)" which should return a String, and you don't have such a method.

Comment: Ya...Thanks...Now I have changed the RPG prototype for the sendSimpleMail..But now its showing a new error, saying Class not Found error..

Comment: RPG procedure MAILERDEMO in program SAHOON1/MAILERDEMO     
  received Java exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:                     
  javax/mail/Authenticator" when calling method "sendSimpleMail" with          
  signature                                                                    
  "(Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.lang.String;Ljava.lang.String;)V 
  " in class "demo.Mailer".

Comment: You are using JavaMail which needs to be in your classpath, along with the jar files JavaMail needs.  I would suggest that you write a simple main() method which invokes sendSimpleMail() and experiment in QSH with invoking that method.   QSH behaves in this regard like AIX and other Unix systems allowing you to get better error messages, which any Java programmer can help you diagnose.  _Any_ NoClassDefFound or ClassNotFound exception indicates you need to adjust the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

IMO there's no reason at all to compile code on the iSeries ... develop, test, & build the code on a workstation ... then deploy & test the application jar on the host.

Comment: That doesn't help when the problem is with the RPG voodoo to invoke the JVM.